# "Object is possibly undefined" when using Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having an issue with this piece of code, and assuring TypeScript that I know the location won't be undefined (as I'm iterating the People?).

On each line inside `PeopleCard` I'm getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

I'm a little confused as if the Object is being iterated, I'm assuming it can't iterate

```
          {people && Object.keys(people).map((id: string) => (
            <PeopleCard
              location={people[id]}
              onDelete={() => openDeletePeopleModal(locations[id])}
              onEdit={() => openEditPeopleDrawer(locations[id])}
              onClick={() => history.push(`/todo/${todo.id}/people/${people[id].id}`)}
            />
          ))}
```

I get `people` from my Context, and I access it like so:

```
let { people } = selectedTodo;
```

TypeScript believes `selectedTodo` to be of type `ITodo` and `people` to be of type `{ [id: string]: Location } | undefined`. Which seems correct to me.

My types are like so:

```
export type People = {
  id: string;
  peopleName: string;
  address1: string;
  address2?: string;
  address3?: string;
  address4?: string;
  address5?: string;
  town: string;
  postcode: string;
  country: string;
}

export type ITodo = {
  id: string;
  todoName: string;
  todoType: string;
  people?: { [id: string]: People };
};
```

I thought adding another check for undefined in might seal the deal, but whatever I've tried so far hasn't worked. I can just add `!` after each one, but I'd rather not do that if it's easy to fix.

Comment: Hmmm, working in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKwJgDaoLxwDeAsAFBxwCWAJgFxwDOMUlAdgOYDcZFKWuAOQCGAW2D0mLDt3Jwh1alGAMGARgnM2XHnIVKVAJgD8GqdtnzFyhgGYTjTdJ2X9DACz3JWmRRfWArJ6O5hQwEADurKbeOpBMAMYQ1OIOZj5wiQCurMyI0U6kAL4yZKCQsAjIqACSACpJEHAEJLI0+SEIDcJi7elh1BC1Vb2xmDjA9oRwANptqVoAuvQY-MCccMVkm6RkiaxMnQP0dQ1NRFR0cADkNFcANIcQ3SlXrKLA949DKPRXSChXDYyPYHQh8caFM79CAlUgAejhcGy7EyQigyWoZAA8gAjABWwHiMAAdABrYCIBgACnBuAAlMSREIwFSqXMvBw6U0AHxwKkgiC4YnYCDsNnUOmS2EIuAotEYsi01AAMmVcFxBKJZIp1KVDKZLPF7S5eF5-Ig+0FwGFovFkrpnCAA)

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are asking for people by id (`people[id]`)? This way TypeScript cannot guarantee that the `id` you have used really exists in `people` (you are using `Object.keys`, but I don't think existence of the id key can be statically inferred from it). `locations[id]` would be the same issue.

Comment: Probably another solution would be `.map((id: string) => ( people[id] && <PeopleCard (...)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlxXXN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.